# How to use conditional operator in echo statement in php

Tags: php

I have a table called `posts` in my database. It consist of 7 columns `post_id`, `user_id`, `username`, `posted_date`, `posted_time`, `am_or_pm` & `likes`. I want to display **no of likes** next to the like button. If the no of likes is 1 I want to display 1 like and if it is more than 1, then I want to display as **n** likes where n is more than 1, here is my php code

```
$dbposts=DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=:user_id ORDER BY post_id DESC',array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
$posts="";
  foreach($dbposts as $p){
  $post_id=$p['post_id'];
    $posts=htmlspecialchars($p['body']);
    $posted_date=$p['posted_date'];
    $posted_time=$p['posted_time'];
    $am_or_pm=$p['am_or_pm'];
    $likes=$p['likes'];
    if(!DB::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:post_id AND user_id=:user_id',array(':post_id'=>$post_id,':user_id'=>$friend_id))){
    echo '<span id="user-name">'.$first_name.'&nbsp;'.$last_name.'</span> posted on <span id="posted-date">'.$posted_date.'</span> at <span id="posted-time">'.$posted_time.'&nbsp;'.$am_or_pm.' </span> <br> <span id="post">'.$posts.'</span>
    <form  method="post" action="Users_Profile.php?username='.$username.'&post_id='.
                                        $post_id.'">
      <button id="like-button" name="like_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Like <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> </button> <span>'.$likes.' likes </span>
    </form><hr>';
  }
    else{
    echo '<span id="user-name">'.$first_name.'&nbsp;'.$last_name.'</span> posted on <span id="posted-date">'.$posted_date.'</span> at <span id="posted-time">'.$posted_time.'&nbsp;'.$am_or_pm.' </span> <br> <span id="post">'.$posts.'</span>
    <form  method="post" action="Users_Profile.php?username='.$username.'&post_id='.
                                        $post_id.'">
      <button id="unlike-button" name="unlike_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Unlike <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> </button> <span>'.$likes.' likes </span>
        </form><hr>';
    }
}
```

Here is the image to show the problem

[image]

I want to display 1 like and not likes. please help

Comment: What is the problem in your code ? Please point out to specific area.

Comment: it works fine but instead of displaying 1 likes, I want to display 1 like, how to use conditional operator or loops in echo " ";

Comment: `($likes > 1 ? 's' : '')`

Comment: you can check the image in the above link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your foreach loop, you can add one more variable to compute the "like" or "likes" value after defining `$likes` like so:

```
// Using ternary expression
$likeOrLikes = $likes === 1 ? 'like' : 'likes';
```

Then in the specific `span` element, you can do it like:

```
'/* ... */ <span>'.$likes.' '.$likeOrLikes.' </span> /* ... */'
```

Before I end my answer, please note that the answer above is to be consistent to your coding style. Your code has a lot of room for optimisation and readability but that's a question for another day.

Comment: Looks easy enough and works. I'd only point out that using an additional variable for this need could be avoided.

Comment: @RabihMelko I thought so too but the original code is already pretty messy.

Comment: In my opinion, just because the code in itself is messy doesn't mean that it is affordable to make it messier. OP might/will read up on his code and fix it at some point. If he sees that he can avoid wasteful variables, he would have to change it up again. Things like that can be avoided early on

Comment: Thanks y'all it worked but there was a mistake in the above answer, it works when $likeOrLikes = $likes > 1 ? 'likes' : 'like';

Comment: @RabihMelko I totally agree to your point. But the point of this answer is to answer the question, not optimisation. And I believe OP will notice this when doing optimisation and it's really not hard to change it. Peace

Comment: @JoelMathews Welcome mate but I dont understand what you meant. Did it work?

Comment: your code is missing the situation where the number of likes is 0. In that case it is a plural word and you are not including it. @RabihMelko has the right condition where he puts as default "likes" and turn it to "like" just when it is 1

Comment: @LelioFaieta really? I thought it should be "likes" as long as the subject is below 2 unit. Now I learn something new thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @YongQuan you can also see it from OP'e example. Even if it's just a matter of grammar...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in explicitly defining likes in your PHP output.

You can create a condition on your likes variable:

```
if ($likes = 1){$likes .= 'like';}
else {$likes .= 'likes';}
```

Then, in your echo, you remove the explicit likes definition. A sample line from your code would now look like this:

```
<button id="like-button" name="like_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Like <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> </button> <span>'.$likes.'</span>
```

Comment: good point for OP code improvement and for including all possible options

Answer (score 1):

```
($likes == 1)? 'like' : 'likes'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
echo ($number>1)?$number." likes": $number." Like";
```